# Using different mail body for each recipient in c# smtp

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I am sending mails using smtp in C#. I have to send it to multiple email ids. I can do that like so:

```
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add(strEmailTo);
            mailMessage.To.Add(strAdminEmailId);
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(strEmailFrom, strDisplayName);
            mailMessage.Subject = strEmailSubject;
            mailMessage.Body = //needs to vary for every recipient
            mailMessage.To.Add("1@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.To.Add("2@gmail.com");
```

Now the problem is, I also need to alter the mail body for each of these recipients. Is there a way that only the body could be changed for each recipient or do I have duplicate everything?

Comment: Post more code, and if you are creating mail messages with different content they'll have to unique instances of the mailmessage object.

Comment: Edited. Please see the comment.

Comment: I would extract this logic into a method, which you would call for each recipient, something like: CreateMailMessage(string to, string adminId, string emailFrom, string displayName, string subject, string body).  Depending on which of those values are consistent or specified per-recipient.